# Can I store mutiple jQuery variables inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, declare

```
  const allTeams = johnRoster, paulRoster;

  allLinks.on("click", function () {
    $(allTeams).slideDown(400);
  });
```

I declared "johnRoster" and "paulRoster" previously as

```
const johnRoster = $(".john-roster");
const paulRoster = $(".paul-roster");
```

I know I could do `const allTeams = $("john-roster"),$(".paul-roster");` but since I already have these stored in variables I want to know if i can use the variables instead.

How can I do this?

Comment: *"I know I could do const allTeams = $("john-roster"),$(".paul-roster");"* That is not doing what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To join two jQuery objects together you can use `add()`:

```js
const $johnRoster = $(".john-roster");
const $paulRoster = $(".paul-roster");

let $allTeams = $johnRoster.add($paulRoster);
$allTeams.on("click", function() {
  $allTeams.slideDown(400);
});
```

This is obviously assuming you have them selected separately already. If that's not the case you can just use a single selector:

```
let $allTeams = $('.john-roster, .paul-roster');
```